# Add extra user field

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor app I use the default `accounts` package, which gives me the default login and registration functionality. Now I want to add an extra field to user, say `nickname`, and for the logged in user the possibility to edit this information.

For editing the profile I suppose I should be doing something like this:

```
Template.profileEdit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!Meteor.user())
      throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login first");

    var currentUserId = this._id;

    var user = {
      "profile.nickname": $(e.target).find('[name=nickname]').val()
    };

    Meteor.users.update(currentUserId, {
      $set: user
    }, function(error){
      if(error){
        alert(error.reason);
      } else {
        Router.go('myProfile', {_id: currentUserId});
      }
    });

  }
});
```

But I doesn't store the info if I look in Mongo. Also when showing the profile, `{{profile.nickname}}` returns empty. What is wrong here?

Edit: added `collections\users.js` to show permissions:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function (userId, doc) {
    if (userId && doc._id === userId) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});

Meteor.users.deny({
  update: function(userId, user, fieldNames) {
    return (_.without(fieldNames, 'profile.nickname').length > 0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I believe that should do the job, although I haven't actually run the code.  The idea is certainly right.

The main things to be aware of are:

1. The necessity to allow the user doc to be edited from the client with an appropriate `Meteor.users.allow()` block on the server, assuming you're going to remove the "insecure" package (which you need to before doing anything in production).
2. The fact that ["by default the server publishes username, emails, and profile"](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user), so you'll need to write a `Meteor.publish` function on the server and subscribe to it if you want to expose any other fields within the user document to the client once you've removed the "autopublish" package (which again, you really should).

Comment: This works, but when I look into the database, I don't see a ``full_name`` attribute stored?

Comment: Are you using the `meteor mongo` shell to look at it?

Comment: Yes, I have updated ``profile_edit.js`` above to how it is now. When showing the profile, ``{{profile.name}}`` is empty.

Comment: Could it be a permission issue?

Comment: have you got `autopublish` on, and if not have you got a publish function?  actually, you shouldn't need one to see something in `profile`

Comment: Autopublish is off, and I do see the ``username`` in the profile, but not the extra field ``profile.nickname``